[m and ]m are not working in Ruby
I have included these plugins and despite in my ruby file I can't jump back and forth between methods with neither ]m nor [m:
return {
  {
    "mfussenegger/nvim-lint",
    "nelstrom/vim-textobj-rubyblock",
    "vim-ruby/vim-ruby",
    "tpope/vim-bundler",
    "tpope/vim-rake",
    "tpope/vim-unimpaired",
    "tpope/vim-rails",
    "tpope/vim-fugitive",
    --    "bruno-/vim-ruby-fold",
  },
}

I would like some help for the solution of any idea where can I debug/search for it?
Additional info:
I have: nvim 0.10.2, with lazyvim

Could it be one of your plugins created a mapping for ]m? What does :verbose map ]m output when you edit a Ruby file?

This should work with vanilla Neovim (without any plugin).
Depending of the keyboard ]m could be difficult to reach and take more than the default value of timeoutlen.
I personally have adapted the setting to 2s:
set timeoutlen=2000

Remark: As of 16/12/2024 the ]m shortcut for Ruby script is dependent of 'classic' highlighting. When nvim-treesitter is installed it deactivates the 'classic' making the ]m shortcut not working.
]m without Vim syntax (treesitter syntax only)
For Python python.vim addresses the problem by using regular expression search.
You could overload your ruby.vim by having:
~/.config/nvim/after/ftplugin/ruby.vim:
let b:next_toplevel='\v%$\|^(class\|def)>'
let b:prev_toplevel='\v^(class\|def)>'
let b:next_endtoplevel='\v%$\|\S.*\n+(def\|class)'
let b:prev_endtoplevel='\v\S.*\n+(def\|class)'
let b:next='\v%$\|^\s*(class\|def)>'
let b:prev='\v^\s*(class\|def)>'
let b:next_end='\v\S\n*(%$\|^(\s*\n*)*(class\|def)\|^\S)'
let b:prev_end='\v\S\n*(^(\s*\n*)*(class\|def)\|^\S)'

if !exists('g:no_plugin_maps') && !exists('g:no_ruby_maps')
    execute "nnoremap <silent> <buffer> ]] :<C-U>call <SID>Ruby_jump('n', '". b:next_toplevel."', 'W', v:count1)<cr>"
    execute "nnoremap <silent> <buffer> [[ :<C-U>call <SID>Ruby_jump('n', '". b:prev_toplevel."', 'Wb', v:count1)<cr>"
    execute "nnoremap <silent> <buffer> ][ :<C-U>call <SID>Ruby_jump('n', '". b:next_endtoplevel."', 'W', v:count1, 0)<cr>"
    execute "nnoremap <silent> <buffer> [] :<C-U>call <SID>Ruby_jump('n', '". b:prev_endtoplevel."', 'Wb', v:count1, 0)<cr>"
    execute "nnoremap <silent> <buffer> ]m :<C-U>call <SID>Ruby_jump('n', '". b:next."', 'W', v:count1)<cr>"
    execute "nnoremap <silent> <buffer> [m :<C-U>call <SID>Ruby_jump('n', '". b:prev."', 'Wb', v:count1)<cr>"
    execute "nnoremap <silent> <buffer> ]M :<C-U>call <SID>Ruby_jump('n', '". b:next_end."', 'W', v:count1, 0)<cr>"
    execute "nnoremap <silent> <buffer> [M :<C-U>call <SID>Ruby_jump('n', '". b:prev_end."', 'Wb', v:count1, 0)<cr>"

    execute "onoremap <silent> <buffer> ]] :call <SID>Ruby_jump('o', '". b:next_toplevel."', 'W', v:count1)<cr>"
    execute "onoremap <silent> <buffer> [[ :call <SID>Ruby_jump('o', '". b:prev_toplevel."', 'Wb', v:count1)<cr>"
    execute "onoremap <silent> <buffer> ][ :call <SID>Ruby_jump('o', '". b:next_endtoplevel."', 'W', v:count1, 0)<cr>"
    execute "onoremap <silent> <buffer> [] :call <SID>Ruby_jump('o', '". b:prev_endtoplevel."', 'Wb', v:count1, 0)<cr>"
    execute "onoremap <silent> <buffer> ]m :call <SID>Ruby_jump('o', '". b:next."', 'W', v:count1)<cr>"
    execute "onoremap <silent> <buffer> [m :call <SID>Ruby_jump('o', '". b:prev."', 'Wb', v:count1)<cr>"
    execute "onoremap <silent> <buffer> ]M :call <SID>Ruby_jump('o', '". b:next_end."', 'W', v:count1, 0)<cr>"
    execute "onoremap <silent> <buffer> [M :call <SID>Ruby_jump('o', '". b:prev_end."', 'Wb', v:count1, 0)<cr>"

    execute "xnoremap <silent> <buffer> ]] :call <SID>Ruby_jump('x', '". b:next_toplevel."', 'W', v:count1)<cr>"
    execute "xnoremap <silent> <buffer> [[ :call <SID>Ruby_jump('x', '". b:prev_toplevel."', 'Wb', v:count1)<cr>"
    execute "xnoremap <silent> <buffer> ][ :call <SID>Ruby_jump('x', '". b:next_endtoplevel."', 'W', v:count1, 0)<cr>"
    execute "xnoremap <silent> <buffer> [] :call <SID>Ruby_jump('x', '". b:prev_endtoplevel."', 'Wb', v:count1, 0)<cr>"
    execute "xnoremap <silent> <buffer> ]m :call <SID>Ruby_jump('x', '". b:next."', 'W', v:count1)<cr>"
    execute "xnoremap <silent> <buffer> [m :call <SID>Ruby_jump('x', '". b:prev."', 'Wb', v:count1)<cr>"
    execute "xnoremap <silent> <buffer> ]M :call <SID>Ruby_jump('x', '". b:next_end."', 'W', v:count1, 0)<cr>"
    execute "xnoremap <silent> <buffer> [M :call <SID>Ruby_jump('x', '". b:prev_end."', 'Wb', v:count1, 0)<cr>"
endif

if !exists('*<SID>Ruby_jump')
  fun! <SID>Ruby_jump(mode, motion, flags, count, ...) range
      let l:startofline = (a:0 >= 1) ? a:1 : 1

      if a:mode == 'x'
          normal! gv
      endif

      if l:startofline == 1
          normal! 0
      endif

      let cnt = a:count
      mark '
      while cnt > 0
          call search(a:motion, a:flags)
          let cnt = cnt - 1
      endwhile

      if l:startofline == 1
          normal! ^
      endif
  endfun
endif

]m with Vim syntax
You could reactivate Vim syntax for ruby by having the following autocmd:
autocmd FileType ruby set syntax=on

Or in lua:
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd({'FileType'}, {pattern={'ruby'}, command='set syntax=on'})




This should work with vanilla Neovim (without any plugin).
I've downloaded a fresh Nvim into a dir and launched loaded a ruby file and stil couldn't ]m and [m..




I also have noticed that the ]m shortcut is not working for Ruby script if nvim-treesitter is activated.
How do I deactivate nvim-treesitter?



Also if I deactivate treesitter will I loos the highlight/autoformatter/foldingunfolding/indenting?

There are alternatives to treesitter for that. But if, like for me, disabling treesitter solves your problem then we should probably consider that there is an issue in the Neovim standard that should be reported (treesitter is considered near standard) in Neovim issue tracker.

How do I disable treesitter?

treesitter is a plugin: nvim-treesitter. If you didn't install it you don't have to disable it.

Well, I installed lazy-vim so it comes preinstalled...

Then you rely on having the problem solved at standard level :-|

I would give a try to disable then see how it works then enable it back. You haven't asnwered my question: "How do I disable treesitter? "

I am also interested in the other alternatives for treesitter, can You please share those as well? thx

In the above script I changed: g:no_python_maps to g:no_ruby_maps and now it works well

Thanks for the feedback!

I have created an issue #464 for the vim-ruby maintainer.

I saw, also saw that regex has a constrain to not recognize method definitions which are just part of strings and not actual method definitions. so a treesitter query would be the perfect solution
